# Why do objects traveling faster appear shortened rather than elongated?

Tags: special-relativity

I'm sure this seems like a stupid question but I hope someone can try to explain it as if to a child...

This relates to Lorentz contraction. Why do objects in motion relative to the observer not get *longer*?

In the train example. A stationary observer is at the middle of a train car which is traveling from the observer's left to his right. A flashbulb goes off in the middle of the train car as it passes the observer.

Now, I understand the speed of light is constant from the observer's POV regardless of the speed of the source. So the observer sees the light hit the left side of the car before it hits the right.

If the car is going 0.99x the speed of light, the observer at rest sees the light reach the left side of the car in (let's say?) 1/100th the time it would take if the car was at rest relative to the observer -- so since we're measuring the distance by the constant speed of light, the left end is shorter. That is essentially what the Lorentz contraction is, isn't it? So my question is: If that's true, then why wouldn't the observer also see it take 99x longer for the light to catch up with the right end of the car -- making the car appear exponentially longer until, if it were going at the speed of light, it would appear infinitely long to the right of the observer and infinitely short to his left?

In trying to understand this, I found these two diagrams on Wikipedia, and what I noticed was that the bottoms of the vertical sticks aren't in the same place. And if they were, then more speed would make the left side shorter approaching zero, and the right side longer approaching infinity.

[image]
[image]

Comment: *Now, I understand the speed of light is constant from the observer's POV regardless of the speed of the source*, It's ALWAYS CONSTANT, that's the whole point.

Comment: I get that. So if you shined a light at the back of an object moving at light speed, it would never reach that object would it? So why is the light not taking forever to reach the front of the train from the outside observer's perspective?

Comment: It wouldn't if that light came from a clock any advance in time would be impossible to read from the moving object too.

Comment: If the light takes forever to reach the front of the train, or to get from the front of the train back to the observer, and since we know light travels at a constant speed, then doesn't that mean the train becomes infinitely long?

Comment: No, because you don't measure it like that. To measure the length of the train you have to "*look*" at both ends simultaneously. And you can't do that along the direction of movement if it moves as fast as light (which is impossible of course) because you can't actually see any of the ends. You see, simutlaneity is not a simple concept in special relativity. So you need to read about it more, in order to understand why the relative movement affects it.

Comment: Okay, so tell me if I have this right - you put a clock on both ends of the train. From your perspective when you look, you know it's 12:00. The light from the clock on the left reaches you at the same time as the clock reaches you, so that side shows a later time and appears compressed. The clock on the right side of the train reaches you as normal, so it still shows 12:00 (and will not appear to advance). Is that it? And then -- so the compression only appears to happen left of your position, not to your right?

Comment: I don't understand, are the clocks in the same inertial frame as you are? This: "*so the compression only appears to happen left of your position, not to your right?*" is certainly wrong. But I still don't understand what you mean. And be very careful when you say "*at the same time*" in this context. If two beams of light comming from tow points in space reached your eyes simultaneously they have to be at the same distance from you for the events that generated the light to be simultaneous.

Comment: No - I mean if the clocks are stuck to the side of the train, but synchronized by you from outside. Then the clock to the left of you would seem to advance and move towards you until the left half of the train passed you, then it would freeze... but the one to your right would remain frozen where you set it... right? (train is moving from left to right)

Comment: Titles are important. The title of this post could be improved; as written, the title of this post contains no information. Every post on this site is a question, and the fact that this one is about special relativity is in the tags. Please see our [FAQ on writing question titles](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your perception is correct in regards to the events you consider, but the conclusion does not contradict the concept of length contraction.

> In short, what you are looking at are *simultaneous events in the train's rest frame*. These do measure the length of the train in the rest frame, but **not** its contracted length as seen by the 'stationary' observer. The reason is that with respect to the stationary observer these events are **no longer simultaneous**  due to relativity of simultaneity. In fact, as you correctly observe, to the stationary observer they appear separated by an interval of time that goes to infinity as the speed of the train approaches that of light. Correspondingly, the distance between them as seen by the stationary observer also goes to infinity, and there is nothing wrong with that!
>
> So where does length contraction come from? Actually it comes from the fact that the stationary observer measures the train length, as he observes it, *by using events that are simultaneous in his stationary frame*, but not simultaneous in the train's frame.

At this point I prefer to back up my statements with a bit of math to avoid misunderstandings, since there seem to be plenty when it comes to this topic.

Let O be the stationary observer and O' be the train's observer (at rest in the train's frame) in relative motion at velocity $v = \beta c$ ($\beta = \frac{v}{c}$, $\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}$). Take the origin of O' in the center of the train as usual and let A be the left (rear) end of the train, and B the right (forward) end. Let the length of the train be $2L$, such that the positions of A and B wrt O' are $x_A' = -L$ and respectively $x_B'=L$.

- In his frame, O' measures the train's length by using events that are simultaneous at A and B. We could argue that this is not necessary since A and B are at rest wrt O', but the procedure must be the same regardless of whether it is applied to objects at rest or in motion. Since there is no better way to properly define it for objects in motion, we also extend the procedure as such for objects at rest. So lets say that O' measures the distance between A and B using events $\mathcal{A} = (-L, ct'_0)$ and $\mathcal{B} = (L, ct'_0)$ at his time $ct'_0$. What does the stationary observer O see instead? To him event $\mathcal{A}$ has coordinates 
  $$ 
  x_A = \gamma(x_A' + \beta ct'_0) = \gamma(-L + \beta ct'_0)\\
  ct_A = \gamma(ct'_0 +\beta x_A') = \gamma(ct'_0 -\beta L)
  $$ 
  while event $\mathcal{B}$ occurs at 
  $$
  x_B = \gamma(L + \beta ct'_0) = x_A + 2 \gamma L\\ 
  ct_B = \gamma(ct'_0 + \beta L) = ct_A + 2 \beta \gamma L
  $$ 
  Obviously he observes $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ occurring at a distance 
  $$
  x_B - x_A = 2 \gamma L \equiv \gamma( x_B' - x_A') > ( x_B' - x_A') = 2L
  $$ 
  and *separated in time* by 
  $$
  c\Delta t = ct_B - ct_A = 2 \beta \gamma L \equiv \beta (x_B - x_A) > 0
  $$
  These are the two events you were considering and, again obviously, they don't show a length contraction, but a length dilation! Yep, but this length dilation occurs between non-simultaneous events, so it cannot measure the train length as it is observed by O.
- Let's see how O *really* measures the train's length. For this purpose O has to consider events or observations $\bar{\mathcal{A}} = (\bar{x}_A, ct_0)$ and $\bar{\mathcal{B}} =  (\bar{x}_B, ct_0)$ that are *simultaneous with respect to him* at some time $ct_0$, although in O' they still occur at the same locations $x_A' = -L$ and $x_B' = L$, at the train's ends. This means that the relation between the coordinates of $\bar{\mathcal{A}}$ and $\bar{\mathcal{B}}$ in the two frames must be
  $$
  \bar{x}_A = \gamma ( -L + \beta c\bar{t}_A')\\
  ct_0 = \gamma (c\bar{t}_A' -\beta L)
  $$
  and
  $$    
  \bar{x}_B = \gamma ( L + \beta c\bar{t}_B')\\
  ct_0 = \gamma (c\bar{t}_B' + \beta L)
  $$
  If we eliminate the O' times $c\bar{t}_A'$ and $c\bar{t}_B'$, and then look at the distance between $\bar{\mathcal{A}}$ and $\bar{\mathcal{B}}$ as observed in O we obtain
  $$
  \bar{x}_B - \bar{x}_A = \gamma(L + \frac{\beta}{\gamma}ct_0 - \beta^2 L - (-L) - \frac{\beta}{\gamma}ct_0 - \beta^2 L) = \gamma (1- \beta^2) 2L 
  $$ 
  or 
  $$
  \bar{x}_B - \bar{x}_A = \frac{2L}{\gamma}
  $$

> In other words, O does see the train length contracted by a factor of $\frac{1}{\gamma}$, although he sees distances between events that are simultaneous in O' as *dilated* by a factor of $\gamma$.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying hard to understand the equations but some of the math is beyond me. I need to visualize it. Tell me if I this is right? To do an experiment, you'd put two lights, on the front & back of the train, and time them so they'll blink synchronously for O, but *asynchronously* for the O'. So the front one will blink earlier in the O' frame. And because it has to blink earlier than the back light, the front of the train has traveled less distance at the time when the front light source is when it blinks, thus comes from a point farther back/left in space ...?

Comment: Do O and O' agree on an absolute point in 3D space where each light is when it blinks, even though the front light appears to blink earlier for O' ? Maybe that's been my misunderstanding -- I thought the light actually WAS further back for O' and further ahead along the path for O when it appears to blink for each of them...

Comment: About visualizing the situation: yes, that's about the right idea. Another way to imagine the experiment is to replace the blinking lights with clocks (digital ones can function simultaneously as blinking lights). If O reads and compares them at the same instance of _his_ time, he finds that the front one always shows an earlier time than the rear one, as you correctly figured it out.

Comment: As for agreeing on points: This is the really tricky part in relativity compared to Galilean mechanics. Observers agree on _events_, as in "object A passes by object B", but read different coordinates for the same event, both in space (no surprise there, since they are in relative motion) _and in time_ (that's the tricky part, since our intuition tells us to expect the _same_ time).

Comment: So lights/clocks that O' sees as being stationary wrt him on the train and blinking simultaneously, appear to O as moving (that's ok) and blinking at different times (oops). In fact O sees lights/clocks in O' blinking both out of sinc _and at different rates_ compared to his clocks, due to time dilation.

Comment: In other words, yes, your misunderstanding comes from the fact that you try to equate simultaneous events in O' (the blinking lights and the conclusion that "the light actually WAS further back for O' ") with simultaneous events in O (measuring the position of the train at the same time _in O_). As for the math: it's just Lorentz transforms from O' coordinates to O coordinates. If using $\beta$, $\gamma$ bothers you at this point, just replace them with their expressions in $v$ and $c$. In any case, deducing them is one thing, but once you have them things become a lot easier.

Comment: Thank you - by agreeing on a point in space, I meant "passing something" in both frames -- that's exactly what I needed to clarify my misunderstanding. So if a light flashes next to an object, it is next to that object for both parties even though the time of the event appears different. True? The hard part for me wrt visualizing has been that I've intuitively seen the *spatial position in relation to other objects* differently for each observer, to accommodate the time difference (b/c it's measured in light which is only visible when it arrives).

Comment: I assumed that if clocks were synchronized to O' then O would not be able to see the front light at all until the light returned from it, which would take longer than the back light -- making the space appear to dilate. So this experiment assumes previous light was coming from the train. What if O had to measure length by external light reflected off the train... which frame would that light take? Specifically if the experiment starts w/ the train in motion and O in the center. Or let's say a millisecond later than that. Would the train's length then appear to dilate infinitely forward?

Comment: I did do a thought experiment with arms and legs about light reflecting from an object traveling away from you at light speed and I understand the square root component in the length equation now - I can visualize that. For every light-second it goes away from you in one second of your time, it's pow(2) time for reflected light to get back. Is that why that's there? I'm still a little confused on whether light emanates from a "clock" or whether it starts at your position and makes a round trip. (sorry - just realized that reflection would be ^2*^4?)

Comment: "So if a light flashes next to an object, it is next to that object for both parties even though the time of the event appears different. True?" Correct. "I've intuitively seen the spatial position in relation to other objects differently for each observer, to accommodate the time difference..." Accounting for time difference **is** always necessary whenever you use light beam reflections and  propagations, **but**: keep in mind relativity of simultaneity. Events at different locations that are simultaneous for one observer, are no longer simultaneous for other, moving observers.

Comment: "I assumed that if clocks were synchronized to O' then O would not be able to see the front light at all until the light returned from it": You attempted to use a "light beam" experiment, which is fine, but not necessary. Imagine O setting up a network of stationary and synchronized sensors that can record the passing of an object by any position and at any time. The sensors would need time to transmit the data, but the recording act itself does not depend on O being able to "see" the train through a light beam propagating from that location.

Comment: "What if O had to measure length by external light reflected off the train... which frame would that light take?" Both frames! Light beams will propagate regardless of whether they are observed or not. Conversely, both observers will be able to follow their propagation and reflections at the ends of the train. But O and O' will find different space and time coordinates for the same reflection events.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think this clears up my question... I realize that I've been seeing it in a backwards way. I really appreciate that you treated my question seriously and helped me to understand (even though I am trying to "see" it instead of calculate it). I would enjoy buying you a beer and talking about this more, but - since I can't at the moment - thank you and cheers.

Comment: Welcome. I was typing the following while you responded, so I'd rather post it all anyways. Hope it helps!

Comment: I would really like to understand: "Conversely, both observers will be able to follow their propagation and reflections at the ends of the train" -- it seems impossible for O to ever see their his reflection from thee front end of the train because the exponential distance over a curved space-time between source and reflection keeps getting larger than the space-distance... hah. I am glad that wasn't my question this time but I will probably ask it soon.

Comment: "Specifically if the experiment starts w/ the train in motion and O in the center...Would the train's length then appear to dilate infinitely forward?" This is a confusion again: The train's length as seen by O **always contracts**. But O will still record the reflections at train's ends in locations separated by a _dilated distance_.

Comment: **This distance however is not the train's length**: it is defined by events that are not simultaneous to O. To find the correct length of the train O must located its ends at the same instance of his own time. Another way out in this specific experiment (O and O' coinciding at the start) is to consider the simultaneous return of both light beams to O', in the center of the moving train.

Comment: Then O finds the total propagation time in terms of his observed train length $\bar{L}$ as $ct = 2\frac{2\bar{L}}{1-\beta} + 2\frac{2\bar{L}}{1+\beta}$ and can use time dilation to relate this to the propagation time observed by O' for the rest length, $ct' = 2 (2L)$. The result is still length contraction by $\gamma$.

Comment: If β is v/c, then does β equal L if v equals 1? What I mean si, if β==c then does the left side of the train cover the entire distance between its original point and the O point at the same speed as c?

Comment: No, no, $\beta$ is adimensional, since it's a ratio of speeds. So if $v \rightarrow c$ then $\beta \rightarrow 1$. In general $-1 \le\beta\le 1$, so $\beta$ can never be $c$ or $L$. On the other hand $-c \le v \le c$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say that at the outset, the observer on the platform has a wristwatch reading 12:00.  He considers his own location to be point $0$.  He considers the right side of the train car to be at location $x$.

The light flashes.  The train car continues to move.  The light catches up to the right side of the train car at (say) 12:01 by the observer's wristwatch, at location $y$ (farther to the right than $x$).

You are saying that if the train car is going very fast, $y$ is going to be very large.  That is true.   But $y$ has little to do with how long the observer thinks the train car is.

The observer says "At 12:00, the light flash went off at point $0$.  At 12:00, the right end of the train was at $x$ (not $y$)!!.  Therefore, at 12:00, the distance from the light flash to the right side of the train car was $x$."

This is intended to explain why your calculation is wrong, which is what you asked about.  It does *not* explain how to get it right, but there are many many many standard sources for that.

Comment: I'm +1'ing this because the description makes sense to me - but I'm still confused. By that definition, let's call the left side of the train point *v*, and the point where that side catches up to its own light *w*, so from left to right we have *v*, *w*, 0, *x*, *y*. If you measure from *v* to *x* i.e. where it is, not where the light catches up to it (or it catches up to the light) then why would there be contraction? If you measure from *w* to *y* then shouldn't the distance be exponentially longer, not shorter?

Comment: You measure from $v$ to $x$.  As to why there should be contraction, you seem to be expecting there to be some totally obvious reason for this.  But if there were a totally obvious reason, somebody before Einstein would have noticed it.  The actual reason is not totally obvious, but not terribly difficult to understand, either.  There are about 8 billion places to read excellent explanations of it.  My favorite is a little book by Mermin called "Space and Time in Special Relativity".

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the train is moving at constant speed (inertial frame of reference) so, to observers within the train, it must behave as if it were stationary.  This means that the light takes the SAME amount of time to reach the left and right edges of the train.

This can be objectively verified by putting two synchronized clocks, one at each end of the train, such that the clocks freeze when light hits them.  Both clocks must have identical readings at the end of the experiment, and this objective reality (clock reading) must be explained by all observers inside and outside the train.

From this identical clock reading, and the constancy of speed of light, we conclude that the path of the light beam must have the same length on the left and right halves **for all observers**.

Imagine a train which is twice as long as high, the light source is at the top of the midpoint, and the clocks are at the two opposite bottom corners.  Imagine an external observer standing at the midpoint of the train.  If the train were stationary, the light beam would have a 45 degree angle on both sides.

But, since the left clock is moving rightwards, the light beam will have a smaller angle, say 30 degrees from vertical.  Given basic geometry, the only way for the beam in the right half to have the same length is for it to have an angle less than 45 degrees from the vertical also.  This can only happen if the leading (right) edge is lagging behind where it "should" be, i.e. the front of the train is shortening.

Comment: Great visual explanation, and I'm sorry if I'm just being dense: Doesn't the observer see the left side light up before the right? If you're stationary and you can watch one clock approaching from the left, and one going away to the right, wouldn't the one on the right appear to count time more slowly? Why is it agreed that it's the *time* between the center and each corner that's unequal from outside, as opposed to the distance in space? Why would it be invalid to presume that the light-triangle's right got longer, which would keep light speed constant and would explain the time difference?